# Changing background color based on page position

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, colors, background

I juste want to change the background color based on the scroll.
Red to blue for exemple...

This code works but how can I change the grey to a color ?

**http://fiddle.jshell.net/schmudde/ffk6phq0/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var alpha = Math.min(0.5 + 0.4 * $(this).scrollTop() / 210, 0.9);
        var channel = Math.round(alpha * 255);
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + channel + ',' + channel + ',' + channel + ')');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fade between colors, you can adjust your code slightly to fade between the channels rather than setting all three to the same value. Based on your blue to red example, see the updated fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/j6tc4e9f/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var alpha = Math.min(0.0 + 0.4 * $(this).scrollTop() / 210, 0.9);
        var channel = Math.round(alpha * 255);
        var channel2 = 255 - Math.round(alpha * 255);
        $("body").css('background-color', 'rgb(' + channel + ',' + 00 + ',' + channel2 + ')');
    });
});
```

Comment: How can change the color ? I don't really understand the process... For exemple, if my beginning color is #e5cec7 and the end is #e6e6e6 ?

Comment: You would need to rework it a bit to get 3 channel fade. You just need to convert the hex to RGB values and give the function the beginning and ending channel values. There may be a better way to do this, but off the top of my head, see the updated fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/ffcagtc6/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 210) {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'blue');
            } else {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
```